# Can someone help me with this conversion to py3

Tags: python

I'm working from Programming Collective Intelligence by Toby Segaran But when converting from Py2 to Py3 can't figure out where I'm drawing this error.

```
def hcluster(rows, distance=pearson):
    distances={}
    currentclustid=-1

    # Clusters are initially just the rows
    clust=[bicluster(rows[i],id=i) for i in range(len(rows))]

    while len(clust)>1:
        lowestpair=(0,1)
        closest=distance(clust[0].vec,clust[1].vec)

        # Loop through every pair looking for the smallest distance
        for i in range(len(clust)):
            for j in range(i+1,len(clust)):
                # Distances is the cache of distance calculations
                if (clust[i].id,clust[j].id) not in distances:

                    distances[(clust[i].id,clust[j].id)]     =distance(clust[i].vec,clust[j].vec)
                    d=distances[(clust[i].id,clust[j].id)]

                    if d<closest:
                        closest=d
                        lowestpair=(i,j)

                # Calculate the average of the two clusters
                mergevec=[
                (clust[lowestpair[0]].vec[i]+clust[lowestpair[1]].vec[i])/2.0
                for i in range(len(clust[0].vec))]

                # Create the new cluster
                newcluster=bicluster(mergevec,left=clust[lowestpair[0]],
                                     right=clust[lowestpair[1]],     distance=closest,
                                     id=currentclustid)

            # Cluster ids that weren't in the original set are negative
            currentclustid-=1
            del clust[lowestpair[1]]
            del clust[lowestpair[0]]
            clust.append(newcluster)

    return clust[0]
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#9>", line 1, in <module>
    clust=clusters.hcluster(data)
  File "C:\Users\Boogz\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\Lib\site-    packages\clusters.py", line 83, in hcluster
    del clust[lowestpair[1]]
IndexError: list assignment index out of range
```

Another thread when I searched for "index error out of range" suggested that that person's error was that they were attempting to write to an element that doesn't yet exist but I can't see where I'm doing this.

Comment: have you tried using `2to3 filename.py`?

Comment: @ritesht93 Nope, I've been attempting to teach myself Py3 by rewriting Py2 programs as though they are originally for Py3

Comment: It would probably be easier if the example was complete enough to be runnable?!

Comment: Can you do us a favor and change the offending line to `i = lowestpair[1]; del clust[i]`, so that one can see which indexing operation fails?

Answer (score 0):

From simply looking at the logic, without any background on what this actually is supposed to do, without a full runnable example, and without knowledge about the referenced book, I have to guess a little, but I think your indention is messed up. Please have a look at this:

```
def hcluster(rows, distance=pearson):
    distances={}
    currentclustid=-1

    # Clusters are initially just the rows
    clust=[bicluster(rows[i],id=i) for i in range(len(rows))]

    while len(clust)>1:
        lowestpair=(0,1)
        closest=distance(clust[0].vec,clust[1].vec)

        # Loop through every pair looking for the smallest distance
        for i in range(len(clust)):
            for j in range(i+1,len(clust)):
                # Distances is the cache of distance calculations
                if (clust[i].id,clust[j].id) not in distances:

                    distances[(clust[i].id,clust[j].id)]     =distance(clust[i].vec,clust[j].vec)
                    d=distances[(clust[i].id,clust[j].id)]

                    if d<closest:
                        closest=d
                        lowestpair=(i,j)

# the following two blocks should be be at the same indention level
# as the clust.append(newcluster) in the very end, as you are otherwise
# only overwriting the same thing unnecessarily each iteration.

        # Calculate the average of the two clusters
        mergevec=[
           (clust[lowestpair[0]].vec[i]+clust[lowestpair[1]].vec[i])/2.0
            for i in range(len(clust[0].vec))]


        # Create the new cluster
        newcluster=bicluster(mergevec,left=clust[lowestpair[0]],
                             right=clust[lowestpair[1]],     distance=closest,
                             id=currentclustid)

# The following block should be outside the i and j loops
# otherwise you delete more then you append back
# thus clust gets too short to delete elements with index len(clust)-1

        # Cluster ids that weren't in the original set are negative
        currentclustid-=1
        del clust[lowestpair[1]]
        del clust[lowestpair[0]]
        clust.append(newcluster)

    return clust[0]
```

I think `mergevec` is supposed to be created for each combination in `lowestpair`. You create it for each combination if `i` and `j`. This is probably not a problem, but hints at the problem:

You are deleting inside the inner for loop. This obviously shortens `clust`. But you get the length of it right in the beginning of the for loop. Thus, if you delete later on, the list is too short for deleting the "last" item in that range.

Comment: You should avoid posting partial answers, as you're judged on them immediately as they appear right now. *Expanding* on a complete answer is great, but just publishing a stub is not really great. Reversed the downvote now.

Comment: I copied the huge code block into the textbox, and simply didn't want to lose it ... I'm not sure whether downvoting 20 seconds later is appropriate, though.

Comment: Stack Exchange creates backups of your unsubmitted answers, so “not losing it” is really a bad argument. If you don’t want to be judged on unfinished answers, don’t post them yet. – That being said, I still have difficulties spotting the difference between this and the original code…

Comment: I simply didn't know that ... any suggestion on how to make the changed indention more visible?!

Comment: @azrael Thanks for this.  You were right, it was an indentation issue. Apparently the book (The Google play version at least) is riddled with them.